# Running terminal commands from Cocoa App in Swift failing: "command not found" but works using Command Line Tool in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I created an App that exports all of my iMessages into an app I use for journaling. It accesses the chat.db file in Libary/Messages/ to do this. This part works great

I was required to use frameworks and Command Line Tools won't allow you to bundle Frameworks in macOS. I would have preferred to for this all to be a script and avoid Cocoa altogether, but was required to use a full Cocoa application because of the need for bundled Frameworks

I can enter commands like `pwd` and get a response back. However, when I try to run the terminal commands for the journaling app, it fails with "command not found"

If I run the exact same command from within terminal, or from within a Swift Command Line Tool in Xcode, it works. However, now that I'm using an actual Cocoa app it won't work.

Here is an example of my code:

```
   let pipe = Pipe()
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
task.arguments = ["-c", String(format:"%@", "dayone2 new 'Hello'")]
task.standardOutput = pipe
let file = pipe.fileHandleForReading
task.launch()
if let result = NSString(data: file.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
    return result as String
}
else {
    return "--- Error running command - Unable to initialize string from file data ---"
}
```

and the response:
`/bin/sh: dayone2: command not found`

Comment: Where is `dayone2` located? It's likely it would need to be added to your `$PATH` or use the absolute path.

Comment: I’m not totally sure, but I’m able to access the command within terminal from any directory. I assume this means some sort of environment variable is not set, but I have no idea where to start with that. I’m just really confused as to why a command line tool built in Xcode works, but I Cocoa app built in Xcode doesn’t

Comment: It works from the command-line because Terminal is using an interactive shell for your user. When you run a script from an application it's not, so it has no idea where to look. Try the command in Terminal `which dayone2` and it should return the absolute path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `"--login"` as the first task argument:

```
task.arguments = ["--login", "-c", "dayone2 new 'Hello'"]
```

and that should fix your error.

Explanation:

When you run Terminal the shell starts up as a login shell, from `man sh`:

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-inter-active shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands  from  the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

Among other things the commands in these files typically set the `$PATH` environment variable, which defines the search path the shell uses to locate a command.

When you run your command line tool in the Terminal it inherits this environment variable and in turn passes it on to the shell it invokes to run your `dayone2` command.

When you run a GUI app there is no underlying shell and the `$PATH` variable is set to the system default. Your error "command not found" indicates that your `dayone2` command is not on the default path.

HTH